# Why won't the div slide up under the above div?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on [this dashboard](http://ac.jabulmer12.com) and can't seem to get container 3 to slide up under container 1, can any one spot why?

Comment: All .grid elements are floating to the left. So, Container3 is after Container2, and because of that, he "don't know" there is empty space above. You can use two columns: in first column put Container1 and Container3 and in second column put Container2 and Container4. In that case, there is no empty space.

Comment: just a comment on your markup: you use heading one for both the page and the grid cell's titles - you should use h1 for page and h2 for cells to show the different levels of the hadings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour when working with floats. To solve this, you could eather resort to javascript, or change the formating of your html. Something like this should work:

```
<div class="col">
 <div id="container1">...</div>
 <div id="container3">...</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
 <div id="container2">...</div>
 <div id="container4">...</div>
</div>
```

when you now float the col instead of the containers you should get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

What you linked to is basically just a demonstration of how css floats work. There's no straight-forward fix to make floats act differently, but you might want to take a look at masonry, a javascript solution: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

Even better, you may want to look at [Masonry's "big brother" Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) which can arrange layouts in even more ways; yet is simple to implement. Also works very well on mobile touch screen devices.